# How to check when an artifact was deployed in Maven?

Tags: maven

A simple question, but I couldn't find the answer here (started searching the Maven docs, but I suppose someone should know this out of the cuff...)

How do I check when was a specific artifact deployed to a Maven repository?

Comment: Usually you can look into the repository and see the date of the files...I'm not sure what you exactly asking for?

Comment: @khmarbaise exactly that - the command to "look into the repository" and see the date. I know it's a trivial question, but I'm not experienced with Maven, and I couldn't find a search term that would bring me the answer (tried stuff like "maven deploy date", "maven artifact deploy time", etc, etc...)

Comment: @khmarbaise or do you mean I should look in the repo on my local disk and check the dates there? o.O

Comment: I don't know if you want to check your own artifact or a thrid party's, neither if your talking of your own repo or a repo to which you have no direct access... But if you want to check your own artifact on a repo where you browse the directory structure, there is a file named maven-metadata-local.xml which contains a lastUpdated field formatted as YYYYMMDDHHMISS.

Comment: @StephaneM it's in between :) the artifact was uploaded by someone else at my work - I have direct access, but it wasn't deployed from my computer. However, following your lead I did find a file called "maven-metadata-central.xml" in my local disk with a "lastUpdated" field, I think that's what I was looking for! (maybe you could write that as an answer so I can "accept" it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browse the Maven repo directory structure to the relevant artifact, there is a file named maven-metadata-central.xml which contains a lastUpdated field formatted as YYYYMMDDHHMISS.